# active Https for angular 6 application

Tags: angular, https

I have an angular 6 app deployed on tomcat web server. Also, the server side of the app is written by java spring framework deployed on other tomcat web server.
I want to active secure SSL for my all app in general: between my users browser to my server and also, between my angular server and java server.
What should I do for enabling HTTPS? Thanks.

Comment: try this tutorial https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/

Comment: @AntoAntony that won't work since OP is using tomcat, and not a self deployed app

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad but I'm going to formulate an answer.

SSL is about encrypting traffic between a client and a server, and before that, it needs to validate the identity of the server. In order to do that, it needs a certificate.

If your website is public, you can buy one, it's very efficient and quite easy to set up. Or you can use a certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/, more difficult to set up, but free.

If your website is private, then you can look into your organization if there is an authority that delivers private certificates.

Once you have a certificate, you have to install it on an HTTP web server over your tomcat (Apache and Nginx are the most used ones)

The HTTP web server could also be used as a reverse proxy, to serve your backend and your frontend on the same domain, which is much cleaner than serving them on different domains since it forces you to enable cross-domain requests and that's a consequent security flaw. That would also let you enable SSL for both the frontend and the backend.